# Как узнать максимальное значение n-символьной маски?

Tags: c#

Стоит задача генерации последовательности номеров. Допустим есть номер

```
898811122xxx
```

Как мы видим `xxx` — это маска. Чтобы сгенерировать эту последовательность можно воспользоваться методом For, однако я не знаю как определить максимальное значение 3-значного числа ( у нас в строке номера xxx). Для данной маски это число 999. Подскажите алгоритм определения этого значения в коде c#.

Comment: Не до конца ясна задача, у вас есть маска и по ней необходимо перебрать все варианты? Или по маске найти максимально возможное число которое ей удовлетворяет?

Comment: У меня есть маска. Допустим xxxx - максимальное число для этой маски 9999. Как алгоритмически узнать это число?

Comment: `int.Parse(mask.Replace('x', '9'))` - как-нибудь так не работает?

Comment: Правильная формула будет вида: power в степени length минус один. Допустим, x - десятичное число, три икса подряд -- это 10 в степени три минус единица. Если х - это буква русского алфавита, то это 33 в степени три минус один. Для десятичных и только десятичных можно упростить до комментарием выше заменой на девятки. Ответом расписывать лень.

Comment: Иксы в маске всегда идут последовательно? Если нет, то генерация максимума сама по себе не поможет, а `for` будет неэффективен. Будет лучше уточнить формат.

Comment: @defaultlocale Похоже, что это просто генерация номеров телефонов по шаблону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимальное значение n-значного числа в десятичной системе можно сгенерировать в виде строки так:

```
var maxValueString = new string('9', n);
```

затем нужно будет преобразовать в числовой тип. В зависимости от `n` это может быть `int`, `long`, `BigInteger`:

```
int maxValue = Int32.Parse(new string('9', n)));
```

Comment: Пардон, похоже доконца не донес свою мысль.

Comment: У меня есть маска. Допустим xxxx - максимальное число для этой маски 9999. Как алгоритмически узнать это число?

Comment: @Radzhab, `(10^n)-1`

Comment: @Grundy ну и обобщите на буквы или другие символы, как у меня в комментарии и оформите ответом.

Comment: @AK _Ответом расписывать лень. – A K 1 минуту назад_ :-D

Comment: @Radzhab максимум для 4 символов можно вывести так: `Int32.Parse(new string('9', 4)));` А вообще лучше бы уточнить *основную* задачу, а то не совсем ясно для каких целей Вам нужен максимум

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того, сколько может быть различных символов в маске (power):

```
var mask = "XXX";
var power = '9' - '0' + 1; // 10
var size = Math.Pow(power, mask.Length) - 1;
```

Здесь power = 10 для символов от 0 до 9.

Допустим, у нас `X` - это символ от `А` до `Z`, тогда:

```
var power = 'Z' - 'A' + 1; // 26
```

В более общем случае подряд идущих символов - это `maxchar - minchar + 1` (количество вариаций символов).

Comment: @Regent Спасибо за комментарий, писал не вдумываясь. Разумеется, лишний каст.